# Is there any way to call advice() on a loaded class's methods before the ByteBuddy agent?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have implemented a simple agent as below. It works for my custom `Foo.class`, but I couldn't assign `advice` for the `java.net.URL` class.

Example test code;

```
    public class AgentTest {

    @Test
    public void advice() throws IOException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        File temp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp").toFile();
        Map<TypeDescription, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(URL.class), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(URL.class));
        ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(temp, ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.Target.BOOTSTRAP, ByteBuddyAgent.install()).inject(map);

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .disableClassFormatChanges()
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REBASE)
                .type(is(URL.class).or(is(Foo.class)))
                .transform(
                        new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                                .advice(
                                        isMethod().and(isPublic()).and(named("openConnection")).or(named("myMethod")),
                                        FooAdvice.class.getName()
                                )
                )
                .installOnByteBuddyAgent();

        foo.myMethod();
    }

    public static class FooAdvice {

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        public static void enter() {
            System.out.println("1- method entered !");
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        public static void exit() {
            System.out.println("2- method exited");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any specific approach to binding `advice`'s java.net.URL class methods so that the class is loaded before the `ByteBuddy` agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael is right, as usual. I want to elaborate on your question a bit more, though: You are having a bootstrapping problem here:

- The advice needs to be on the bootstrap class path, otherwise it cannot be used with the bootstrap class `URL`.
- The advice needs ByteBuddy because of the annotations. So BB also has to be on the bootstrap class path.
- If you put your sample code into a single class and also use the BB agent library from there, that one also needs to be on the bootstrap class path. I.e. if you want to run this code

```java
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;

class AgentTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .ignore(none())
      .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
      .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
      .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
      .with(AgentBuilder.InstallationListener.StreamWriting.toSystemError())
      .type(is(URL.class).or(is(Foo.class)))
      .transform(
        new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
          .advice(
            isMethod().and(isPublic()).and(named("openConnection")).or(named("myMethod")),
            FooAdvice.class.getName()
          )
      )
      .installOnByteBuddyAgent();

    new Foo().myMethod();
  }

  public static class Foo {
    public void myMethod() throws IOException {
      new URL("https://google.de").openConnection();
    }
  }

  public static class FooAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void enter(@Advice.Origin Method method) {
      System.out.println("Entering " + method);
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void exit(@Advice.Origin Method method) {
      System.out.println("Exiting " + method);
    }
  }

}
```

you need to add something like this on the Java command line:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:/path/to/my-classes;/path/to/byte-buddy-1.10.13.jar;/path/to/byte-buddy-agent-1.10.13.jar ... AgentTest
```

Then you get this output:

```
[Byte Buddy] BEFORE_INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer@27bc2616 on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@3941a79c
[Byte Buddy] REDEFINE BATCH #0 [2 of 2 type(s)]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM AgentTest$Foo [null, null, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM java.net.URL [null, null, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] REDEFINE COMPLETE 1 batch(es) containing 2 types [0 failed batch(es)]
[Byte Buddy] INSTALL net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer@27bc2616 on sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@3941a79c
Entering public void AgentTest$Foo.myMethod() throws java.io.IOException
Entering public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Entering public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Exiting public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Entering public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Entering public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Exiting public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Exiting public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Exiting public java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection() throws java.io.IOException
Exiting public void AgentTest$Foo.myMethod() throws java.io.IOException
```

As an alternative, you can use a spring-board Java agent which dynamically puts BB and your transformer onto the bootstrap class path without directly referring to any of their classes. You can subsequently kick off transformation via reflection.

Comment: hi kriegaex, thank you for broad explanation. But, I still wonder is there a way to achieve that without adding any other parameters like -Xbootclasspath/a command. Because, some of monitoring technologies just runs with adding `java -javaagent=myagent.jar -jar myapp.jar` javaagent parameter only. Actually, I want to use that agent jar on my other applications as a lightweight monitoring tool. Can I implement that bootstrapping programmatically? I added Boot-Class-Path: myagent.jar into MANIFEST.MF file, now it works for URL class but other custom classes stopped working.

Comment: Why is it acceptable to use `-javaagent` but not `-Xbootclasspath/a`? FWIW, I already gave you a hint about how to do it programmatically: spring-board Java agent injecting transformer and its dependencies into boot class path. In theory, you can even do that without `javaagent` if it is okay that the classes are transformed a bit later, but that depends on your use case. Anyway, this is an all new question, way out of scope of this one. So my answer is the opposite of "broad", it is focused on solving your specific problem here first, not on doing tricky stuff on top of it.

Comment: As for `Boot-Class-Path: myagent.jar`, does the JAR also contain a shaded version of `byte-buddy`? Probably `byte-buddy-agent` would not be needed anymore because you would let the JRE attach your agent. It is difficult to speculate how exactly you are going about this, because your own sample code looks like you do everything manually in a JUnit test or so. Your real use case is hard to determine. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be helpful, then I could help you better.

Comment: no, it doesn't contain a shaded version of byte-buddy. It works with the following command ´java -jar -Xbootclasspath/a:"project.jar;myagent.jar" -javaagent="myagent.jar" project.jar´ but it looks strange, is there any way to achieve without appending both jars to bootclasspath? BTW, agent is looking for its dependencies and also project.jar uses the same dependencies(independently). So I'm trying to bind advice methods that common dependencies' classes' methods.

Comment: How can I build a spring-board java agent that inject my current transformers and its dependencies into boot class path? That sounds reasonable, thanks.

Comment: btw, dependency advices are not working with ´java -jar -Xbootclasspath/a:"project.jar;myagent.jar" -javaagent="myagent.jar" project.jar´

Comment: (1) Why would you put your own project on the boot class path? You shouldn't. (2) Hard to believe that you can modify a bootstrap class like `URL` if ByteBuddy is not on the boot class path, unless your real setup is different from your own sample code and from my answer. (3) As for the other questions, please show me the MCVE I requested first, then I can help you further. Speculations and multiple iterations are for discussion forums, SO is a Q/A site. So please accept + upvote this correct answer, then ask a new question based on the MCVE. I do not like to guess and speculate.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

By default, Byte Buddy ignores the boot and extension/platform loader. You need to set a custom ignore matcher to instrument URL.

Note that this can cause trouble if you instrument classes that Byte Buddy needs itself,especially if Byte Buddy loads these classes itself during the instrumentation of another class.